# Defining a command that scans every arguments' macro "looking for" a token

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

Knowing that every command declaration with conditionally optional arguments, as `\foo{...}` expanding into `\foo[default]{...}` can be defined by `\newcommand\foo[1][default]{...}` or the safer version of:

```
\newcommand\foo{\@ifnextchar[{\@foo}{\@foo[default]}}
\def\@foo[#1]#2{do something with #1 and #2}
```

this kind of "test" however fails if the optional argument is declared after the mandatory one. Therefore (knowing that the order of argument declaration of `\@foo` cannot be changed):

```
\newcommand\foo{\@ifnextchar[{\@foo}{\@foo{}[default]}}
\def\@foo#1[#2]{do something with #1 and #2}
```

will generate errors.

More generally, if `\@bar` is defined such that has to contain two (or more, but the general case is left aside) arguments, but only the *optional* `#2` that doesn't appear just after the control sequence name:

```
\def\@bar#1[#2]{#1 and #2}
```

then, how is it possible to define `\bar` such that this condition:

```
\bar{a}[b] % returns "a and b"
\bar{a}    % returns "a and default"
```

will be met? In this case an internal command inside the definition of `\bar` would scan all of the argument tokens of `\bar` until it finds a `[`; if it doesn't find any, then it'll just declare `\@bar#1[default]`.

This behaviour should be similar to `\@ifnextchar` (say `\@iftoksexist`) with the difference that it will be sufficient for `char` to just exist as argument token:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@iftoksexist#1#2#3{...} % 
\def\mybar{%
  \@iftoksexist{[} % or \@iftoksexist[{...}{...}
  {
  %use "\@mybar#1[#2]"
  }
  {
  %use "\@mybar#1[default]"
  }%
} 
\def\@mybar#1[#2]{#1 and #2\par}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\mybar{lorem}[ipsum]
\mybar{dolor}
\mybar{sit}[amet]   
%
\end{document}
```

In this case, `\@iftoksexist` will search for `[` inside every `\mybar...`, yielding this output:

> [image]

Yet again, after a sufficient number of trials, and looking [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10404/a-macro-with-either-one-or-two-arguments) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar), I haven't had much success.

Comment: You should have a look at `xparse`

Comment: @egreg Right in the weak spot... Unfortunately I haven't put my eye on its documentation for a long time, although it may save some difficulties with the plain TeX understanding of this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just absorb the mandatory argument and “remember” it:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\foo@aux{#1}}{\foo@aux{#1}[default]}%
}
\def\foo@aux#1[#2]{%
  mandatory is `#1', optional is `#2'%
}
\makeatother
```

of course this is not very robust and `\DeclareRobustCommand` should be used.

A syntax like `\foo{a}[b]{c}` where the optional argument has a default value can be defined in a similar way:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\foo@aux{#1}}{\foo@aux{#1}[default]}%
}
\def\foo@aux#1[#2]#3{%
  first mandatory is `#1', optional is `#2', second mandatory is `#3'%
}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mO{default}}{%
  mandatory is `#1', optional is `#2'%
}
```

which is automatically robust. But as a general advice, avoid trailing optional arguments. The `\foo{a}[b]{c}` syntax is just

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mO{default}m}{%
  first mandatory is `#1', optional is `#2', second mandatory is `#3'%
}
```

Note that in the first case spaces will be ignored after `\foo{a}` if no optional argument is present (the reason is how `\@ifnextchar` works).

Comment: The `[default]` should be in the false branch I guess: `\@ifnextchar[{\foo@aux{#1}}{\foo@aux{#1}[default]}`

Comment: @cgnieder You're perfectly right

Comment: @egreg Needless to say, excellent answer as usual. I'll definitely look up xparse now that I have plenty of time ;)

Comment: @AndreaL. Exam session ended?

Comment: @egreg Yeah! But I finished in July; right now I'm preparing some Linear Algebra exercise sheets for my colleagues (with the occasion, I took two birds with one stone) :-)